# how to calculate script run time

Tags: command-line, bash, telnet

Consider this shell redirect:
`telnet towel.blinkenlights.nl >> starWarz`
when it ends, the session will break, detach from host or something like that. I want to know how long the connection lasts. How might I determine this?

Comment: 18m48s if anyone is interested. It conists of 3413 frames, and the fps is around 3. (dang, that was my first guess for fps)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the shells has a builtin named `time`, `bash` has it too. It will show you the actual human time (`real`) a process takes with the CPU time the process spends on user space (`user`) and kernel space (`sys`).

So run the command perpending `time`:

```
time telnet towel.blinkenlights.nl >> starWar
```

At the end `bash` will show the time on STDERR like:

```
real    XmX.XXXs
user    YmY.YYYs
sys     ZmZ.ZZZs
```

Even if you are on a shell that does not have the `time` builtin you have the external `time` command `/usr/bin/time` from the `time` package. The usage is same.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you're looking for the `time` builtin:

```
$ help time
time: time [-p] pipeline
    Report time consumed by pipeline's execution.

    Execute PIPELINE and print a summary of the real time, user CPU time,
    and system CPU time spent executing PIPELINE when it terminates.

    Options:
      -p    print the timing summary in the portable Posix format

    The value of the TIMEFORMAT variable is used as the output format.

    Exit Status:
    The return status is the return status of PIPELINE.
```

It will print a report of the time taken by a command. For example:

```
$ time sleep 3

real    0m3.027s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

The "real" field is the actual time that passes, the same value you would have measured with a watch. So, you can simply do:

```
time telnet towel.blinkenlights.nl >> starWarz
```